# Uploading multiple files with dropzone

Tags: dropzone

For some reason if I set the uploadMutiple option to true when I create a dropzone instance the server side upload script fails to do anything.

The reason I am creating the dropzone programatically is because the upload form exists in a modal popup - called by an AJAX request.

My upload form:

```
<div id="myDropzone" style="height:190px;border:1px blue;border-style:dotted;background-color:white;text-align:center;overflow-y:auto;">
  <br /><br /><br />
  Drop image here or click to upload.
</div>
```

Then in my javascript I turn that div into a dropzone

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", { url: "/tools/news/uploadimage.php", uploadMultiple : true });

            myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
                alert("All files have uploaded ");
                //closeJustPopup('uploadImagePopup');
            });
```

My upload script

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'images';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    //$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $targetPath . date('YmdHis',time()).'.'.$extension;

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

Comment: I have believe my files are uploading so quickly that they are getting the same filename in my uploadimage.php script - I need to find a better way of getting a unique file name.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling about here is the solution - it turns out the uploadMultiple option is NOT required and actually breaks it.  I also added microtime() to my filename in the upload script to ensure it is unique.

Also, I had to reduce parallelUploads to 1.  Most other examples I found online had it set to 10.

Hope this is useful to someone else!!

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", { 
                        url: "/tools/news/uploadimage.php", 
                        parallelUploads: 1,
                        maxFiles: null,
                        processingmultiple() {},
                        sending() {},
                        totaluploadprogress(uploadProgress) {},
                        successmultiple(files, res) {},
                        errormultiple(file, res, xhr) {},
                        queuecomplete() {}

                    }
                );
```

File name in PHP script

```
$targetFile = $targetPath . date('YmdHis',time()) . microtime() . '.'.$extension;
```